# A formula that returns data from a range of two or more columns in one column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

|  |  | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 1 |
| 2 | b | 2 |
| 3 | c | 3 |
| 4 | d | 4 |
| 5 | e | 5 |
| 6 |  | 6 |
| 7 |  | 7 |
|  |  | a |
|  |  | b |
|  |  | c |
|  |  | d |
|  |  | e |

[image]

I want to list all the data in the range A:B as a return value in column C where the formula is written. Empty cells should be ignored.
I've tried getting a specific range of data with the indierct or indexof functions, but I have no idea how to concatenate them into one column in order if the target is more than one column!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
=LAMBDA(z,FILTER(z,z<>""))(FLATTEN(A:A,B:B))
```

- 

[image]

Incase the [new functions](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/200022527?hl=en) have rolled out for you, try:

```
=TOCOL(A:B,1,1)
```

- 

[image]